# Hypothesis testing - critical region

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

When finding the critical region, do you choose the x values closest to the significance level even if its bigger then it or does the value have to be smaller then the significance level.

So if a question asks you to find a critical region at a 5% significance level, if x<=3 = 5.1% and x<=2 = 2%, what would the critical region be?

Answer (score 0):

The critical value would be between 2 and 3, though much closer to 3. The critical region would be everything below this value. Assuming your alternative hypothesis is a one-sided and less than/ below hypothesis.